# A strange codes in c

Tags: c, printf, format-specifiers

There's a strange code here:

```
const double a[] = {0,1,2,3,4};
int main()
{
    double *p = a;
    printf("%f\n",p[2]); //2.000000
    printf("%f\n",p);    //2.000000
}
```

It return 2.000000 ,why?

Comment: is this a trick question? why wouldn't it return the 3rd element of the array?

Comment: result of `printf("%f\n",p);` is UB.

Answer (score 6):

The code

```
printf("%f\n",p);
```

causes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). To print an address (a pointer) which is the type an array name decays to when passed as function argument, you need to

- use `%p` conversion specifier.
- cast the argument to `(void *)`.